# Error while setting expiration of subscription under SaaS with Odoo 10.0 community edition

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I am trying to set new expiration for a company from the following section:

**Saas -> Clients -> Manage Subscription (say for mycompany.com)**

In the form adding a "New expiration" and "Reason of new expiration". After form submission receiving the following error,

```
Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 889, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/saas_portal_sale/wizard/subscription_wizard.py", line 27, in apply_changes
    super(SaasSubscriptionWizard, self).apply_changes()
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/saas_portal/wizard/subscription_wizard.py", line 33, in apply_changes
    self.client_id.change_subscription(expiration=self.expiration_new, reason=self.reason)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/saas_portal/models/saas_portal.py", line 629, in change_subscription
    'value': expiration, 'hidden': True}]})
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/saas_portal_backup/models/saas_portal.py", line 30, in upgrade
    return super(SaasPortalClient, self).upgrade(payload=payload)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/saas_portal/models/saas_portal.py", line 545, in upgrade
    res.append(config_obj.do_upgrade_database(payload.copy(), database_obj))
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/saas_portal/wizard/config_wizard.py", line 86, in do_upgrade_database
    raise Warning('Reason: %s \n Message: %s' % (res.reason, res.content))
Warning: Reason: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 
 Message: 'decimal.precision'
```

**Note:** I can see that the database backup is getting created properly and after that this error is happening.

My server environment is **Ubuntu 16.04** and I am using **Odoo 10.0 community edition**

Comment: Verify if you have model decimal.precision in your addons.

Comment: @KararaMohamed Yes, "decimal.precision" model is there and it has values set for "Product Price", "Discount" etc..